# Python - Bug while appending

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

While working on a project for school I came across a bug in my code. It's meant to store the previously inputted data and then it should be printed at the end of the code.

EX:
If you enter item1 item2 and item3, it's only showing the info for item3 instead of all of the info.

```
groceryHistory = []


stop = 'c'

while stop != 'q':
  item_name = input('Item name:\n')
  quantity = input('Quantity purchased:\n')
  cost = input('Price per item:\n')
#Above Prompts user to enter the item, quantity, and price of the items they're purchasing
  grocery_item = {'name':item_name, 'number': int(quantity), 'price': float(cost)}
  groceryHistory.append(grocery_item)
#Above stores the item within the grocery history list that is held at beginning of code
  stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
#If user enters q, the loop will end. C will start the loop over again.

grand_total = 0

#Calculating totals using the history that is stored
for grocery_item in groceryHistory:
  item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
  grand_total += item_total


print(str(grocery_item['number']) + ' ' + grocery_item['name'] + " @ $"+str(grocery_item['price']) + ' ea $' + str(item_total))

print('Grand total: $' + str(grand_total))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't initialize a variable with a dummy value, use while-True and quit the loop with break at the end. Indent by 4 not by 2 spaces. And I think, you want the `print` inside the for loop:

```
grocery_history = []
while True:
    item_name = input('Item name:\n')
    quantity = input('Quantity purchased:\n')
    cost = input('Price per item:\n')
    grocery_item = {
        'name': item_name,
        'number': int(quantity),
        'price': float(cost),
    }
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
    stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    if stop == 'q':
        break

grand_total = 0
for grocery_item in grocery_history:
    item_total = grocery_item['number'] * grocery_item['price']
    grand_total += item_total
    print(f"{grocery_item['number']} {grocery_item['name']} @ ${grocery_item['price']} ea ${item_total}")

print(f'Grand total: ${grand_total}')
```